# Google Maps doesn't load map's images

Tags: android, google-maps

I implemented an example of android app with google maps, but the map hasn't been correctly loaded. When I zoon in the map gets blur and doesn't load the streets or any other details.

The logcat continuously shows the following message:

```
11-25 00:17:09.657: D/REQUEST(1485): Connection opened to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
11-25 00:17:09.663: D/REQUEST(1485): Open Connection
11-25 00:17:09.932: D/REQUEST(1485): DRD(60): 62|147
11-25 00:17:09.948: D/REQUEST(1485): Close
11-25 00:17:09.950: D/REQUEST(1485): Error processing: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@2c85fd8f not retrying
```

I'm running the app with the android emulator with the following characteristics:

`Device=Nexus S(4.0", 480x800: hdpi)
Target=Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 17
CPU/ABI: Google APIs ARM (armeabi-v7a)`

I already checked my API KEY and it's ok with the Google Developers Console. The SHA-1 key on my debug.keystore is exatcly the as the one on Developers Console, as well as the app package.

I saw a question here in the StackOveflow (http://bit.ly/1xVvo5D) that suggest to remove the following line `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());`. However, as far as I know I'm not using such code. Just to double check, I searched for `HttpsURLConnection` with eclipse Ctrl+H and nothing was found.

The manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- External storage for caching. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- My Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my-api-key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The main activity is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/map" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: The map usually loads the world map, you are able to get the world map? and when you zoom in it gets blur?

Comment: It loads part of the world map, but even that part that is loaded gets blured when I zoom in.

Comment: on emulator or real mobile device? Perhaps slow internet connection?

Comment: With the emulator. I'm using my personal wifi internet, it's 20MB, I think it is not slow.

Comment: Have u tried it on real device?

Comment: It's due to connection problem .I am facing same problem .Its just because when you zoom in google map will shows us new areas according to your zoom level.